# Создание загрузочной флешки вместе с драйверами

Tags: linux, usb, iso, dd, fdisk

Debian не ставится на мой ноутбук, из-за нехватки определенных модулей (сетевых драйверов).
Я записываю `ISO` образ на флешку (делаю загрузочную флешку) с помощью `fdisk` / `dd`
ФС на флешке `FAT32`, затем делаю `dd` образа на флешку, после чего она становится у меня `read-only` и я не могу положить нужный пакет-драйвер в структуру этого устройства. Если примонтировать `ISO` образ Дебиана например в `/mnt` он тоже становится `read-only` (я думал сам образ подредактировать, но так видимо нельзя). Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы я мог после записи образа на флешку, кое - что подредактировать?

Я пробовал делать remount, но по итогу ФС на флешке всё равно `read-only` и положить туда ничего не получается

Может можно пересобрать готовый образ ?

Comment: Максимально тупой вариант - просто взять вторую флешку и скинуть сетевые драйвера на неё?)

Comment: Вариант хороший, но у меня стоит задача именно в процессе установки системы, подлавить необходимые драйвера (то есть чтобы сам Debian взял из каталога нужные пакеты и установил их, а он их и возьмет, просто нужно положить нужный файлик ему в ISO, а вот как это сделать я не знаю)

Comment: Теоретически можно пересобрать образ под себя (но я не умею, может другие подскажут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно есть смысл вытащить все из iso-файла, сделать необходимые операции, и снова создать iso-файл.

```
mkisofs -o destination-filename.iso /home/username/files-for-iso
```

Comment: как вариант кстати, спасибо